# How styled-components affect performance?

Tags: reactjs, performance, styled-components

Is using styled-components slows down the web app more than stylesheets do?

If I care about the performance and don't have any styles that depend on props, should I just ditch styled-components and use stylesheets instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There will always be *some* overhead for a runtime CSS-in-JS library since it's ultimately doing more work. But for that overhead you're also getting a lot of flexibility and power.

Every release we have improved the performance of the library, to the point where the difference is relatively imperceptible (especially when server-side rendering.)

It's entirely up to you to choose which implementation makes the most sense for your project; if all your styles are actually static, then a pure CSS approach will definitely be the most performant. But, that comes with its own caveats in terms of managing your stylesheets, writing efficient selectors, and such.

Comment: Interested to know if there is any performance implications of using it with react-native as the model to set styling rules in that platform is completely different from web

Comment: I see a difference right off the bat, switched a single component to use styled-components, and boom many headaches, lag spikes, jitters on mobile, a huge difference in performance. Demo it on a small project before you make the mistake I did. Before you ask, yes this application is optimized, compressed, etc. Its not even quicker than just writing jsx object styles.

Answer (score 29):

When you have lot of little components, using styled-component rendered, at the same time, the performance overhead can be meaningful. Definitely worth testing to remove styled-component on small elements.

I was using styled-component on a table cells/rows, that can generate 27260 `span` (cell) at once. Using React profiler, my table took around 1050-1250ms to generate, it went to 600-630ms once I remove styled component from rows and cells.

Comment: I have definitely seen the same.

Comment: I also had the same situation with FullCalendar(library) React component, used styled component(which overrides the calendar styles) to wrap the calendar component. I had to apply some conditional styles to each date and more the number of dates I had to customize, more time(around 6s since when I have to loop over about +300 dates) it took for styled component to generate the styles or update the styles lets say on state changes. Instead I had to generate my own styles and insert into the style tag within the component and it greatly improved the performance of the calendar.