# Is it a practise to use styled components and css modules at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, styling

I have recently dived into styled components and I wonder where to actually use them. In my case, 10% of my components are styled ones and the other 90% use CSS modules. Is this a normal practice or should I just not mix these two ways of styling in my project? Is it normal to have a single component that uses CSS modules and is styled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never seen a mix of the both methods, but it's not wrong. It might be a bad pratice thought, you create 2 patterns for the same thing, which can be confusing.

Personal point of view here: I'm now working on 2 projects, one using styled-components and the other css modules.
Styled components are problematic sometimes because if you don't use them correctly, you will destroy your namespace, and not only that, you might also mess up with your HTML tags. I use styled component only to write The page box, all the rest is written using css classes

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  column-count: 1;
  column-gap: 2em;
  background: ${COLOR.lightestGray};

  .column-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
  }

  @media (min-width: ${BREAKPOINTS.mobileMedium}) {
    padding: 0em 2.94em;
  }

  @media (min-width: ${BREAKPOINTS.desktopMedium}) {
    padding: 2em 2.94em;
  }

  @media (min-width: ${BREAKPOINTS.desktopLarge}) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
`;
```

Using Css modules the namespace is safe but you make your component messier like this:

```
      <form className={styles.form}>
        <input className={cn({
          [styles.input]: true,
        })}
          {...nameInput}
          onChange={e => nameInput.onChange(e)}
          // onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Nome do fornecedor"
        />
        <input
          className={cn({
            [styles.input]: true,
            [styles.valid]: validateCNPJ(CNPJ),
            [styles.invalid]: CNPJ && !validateCNPJ(CNPJ),
          })}
          value={CNPJ}
          type="text"
          placeholder="CNPJ"
          onChange={handleCNPJ}
        />
```

Personally I don't like to mix concerns so I would choose only styled-components, that's it, cheers

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Styled Components [degrades performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53538967/6923555). It's not noticeable in small apps, but in large apps with many small components it may be. In such cases, CSS Modules is better.